# Change width of the custom seekbar in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have defined a custom seekbar like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="2dip" />
            <gradient
                    android:startColor="#32CEFE"
                    android:centerColor="#35CEFE"
                    android:centerY="0.75"
                    android:endColor="#3FC4FF"
                    android:angle="270"
            />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>


<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="2dip" />
            <gradient
                    android:startColor="#32CEFE"
                    android:centerColor="#35CEFE"
                    android:centerY="0.75"
                    android:endColor="#3FC4FF"
                    android:angle="270"
            />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>

</layer-list>
```

I tried by adding `android:width="2dip"` but there was no change in the width. I haven't defined width anywhere. I want to make it thinner. How to do that?

Comment: More sleek, as in thinner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the SeekBar wrap into its container you can force it to shrink by adding margin to its left and/or right  side also:

```
    <SeekBar
                    android:id="@+id/seekBar"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_column="0" 
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="-20dp"   
     />
```

Notice the 2 last lines

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
<size android:width="5dp"/>
```